# Titan: Refreshing the graph after adding new vertex or edges

Tags: titan

I am using Titan in Spring Web app. When i add new edge, or delete a vertex its actually deleted but doesn't reflect in my web page. My query still gets the old edges or vertices.

for that to happen i have to restart my application.

I am doing `g.commit()` after each new addition or deletion.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Consider issuing a `g.rollback()` at the start of a new HTTP request to ensure you get a fresh view.  That's how Rexster does things currently.

Comment: `at the start of a new HTTP request ` does that mean before processing each and every  HTTP request made from user side i should call `g.rollback()`

Comment: yes...that will ensure a fresh transaction for the thread handling the request.

Comment: Using `g.rollback()` will effect other read/write operation happening in the titan? any performance issue?

Comment: Other read/write operations should occur in different threads.  All Titan transactions occur within the context of a thread, so it should not interfere.  In fact, a rollback is almost required in the sense that a failure from a previous request not properly handled could result in strange behavior on a future request handled by that thread.  A pre-emptive rollback() is a good way to deal with that as a safety.  Again, this is how Rexster handles such things.  I would not expect performance penalties.

Comment: edited my answer a bit to reflect matthias's explanation of the problem so as to avoid confusion.

Comment: I got same problem, i using tinkerpop3 and cannot find g.rollback(), so is it g.tx().rollback()? One more question: Should I use singleton GraphTraversalSource or do i need spawn new one from titangraph for every each new http request?

Comment: In TinkerPop 3.x, the syntax is `g.tx().commit()` or g.tx().rollback()`. You should try to re-use the `TraversalSource`.

Comment: We added transactions to all our reads because we kept getting cached properties after we updated Vertices. This lead the application to start throwing `ConcurrentModificationException` when the Read load was high. After reading this thread we removed transactions from Reads and are now calling `g.tx().rollback()` at the beginning of a Read instead. It seems to work so far!

Answer (score 7):

To add to Stephen's answer:

The problem here is not the caching layers but the fact that Titan uses transactions for both read and write operations against the graph.
So, what's happening here is that the write operation followed by a g.commit() successfully stores the new data in the graph, but subsequent reads occur in an old transaction (since the former read transaction wasn't committed or rolled back) and hence the changes are visible.

This is correct behavior from a transactional perspective but can be confusing when you don't think of "reads" as transactions.